# Compile-time error when not returning from a method, but not from another dev environment

Tags: c#

In my home development environment, if I don't specify the return variable of a method which returns a value, this is a compile-time error.

However, at work (where I guess Visual Studio settings may differ), the code will still compile fine in this situation.

E.g.

```
string EditString(string s);
```

In my code I can write this (At work):

```
EditString("string here");
```

As you can see, I don't write string s = EditString("..."); But that won't compile at home.

From this method, I would have to write:

```
string s = EditString("abc");
```

If I don't specify explicitly the return variable, what effect does this have on the compiler? (I assume the compiler will automatically just do the assignment)? Where can I check this setting that causes an error if I don't return from a method call?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have the "Display Warnings as Errors" project/solution setting enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have installed a visual studio plugin like FxCop or Resharper which will automatically check your code and you've set its level too high.

The warning you are getting can be ignored, I would disable it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confusing two things.

You *can* write a method with a return type but ignore the returned value:

```
static string EditString(string s)
{
    return "abc";
}

static void Main()
{
    EditString("xyz");  // ok
}
```

But you *cannot* define a method that has a return type but doesn't return a value:

```
static string EditString(string s) // error: not all code paths return a value
{
}
```

Comment: The above I know. I think you're confusing my question as I am referring to only method calls and nothing about definitions (which I know must return in the body if the signature returns a type). See my edit in my first post.

Comment: More to the point, I think your original question was confusing. It would still be better with a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken about the cause of your error at home. It won't create a warning *or* an error.

However, you may have tried to do something similar, but with a property or indexer. You can't invoke a property without using the result - it's not a statement expression on its own. In other words:

```
string[] x = ...;
x.Length; // Invalid
x[0]; // Invalid
int y = x.Length; // Valid
string z = x[0]; // Valid
```

If you still believe you're seeing it with *methods* at home, please post a short but complete example. If you're using a working C# compiler, you can always ignore the return value of a method.

Comment: Not getting the error anymore. This may be due to updates in my resharper and similar tools which I use. I get an error about returning a variable, but only with some framework methods and not with my own custom methods. And yes, your example is much cleaner :)